# How to access cursor state in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-cursor

I am trying to debug an application that interacts with an SQL Server database. It does this in part using database cursors.

While stepping through the application I would like to see the state of a specific cursor using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (which has a connection to the database in use).

How do I do this? Or is there some other tool with which I can do this?

Comment: It would be better if you *didn't* use a cursor at all. There is almost no reason to use cursors, and definitely no reason for a client application to do so. Client-side cursors were replaced by disconnecter recordets almost 20 years ago. Cursors cause scalability problems even with *two* concurrent users

Comment: Why are you using cursors? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos there are cases where the application has a looping process that generates values for particular fields in particular tables to be updated one record, and a few fields, at a time, and the data must be committed before the next loop iteration starts. For those kinds of situations, the update is done though a cursor.

Comment: The app is large, and  in production for more than 15 years. Uses of set-SQL for some things, and cursors for others . It is working well at hundreds of clients, with scores of concurrent users each. To describe in full use of set-based and  cursors would take me days to write, and I wouldn't be allowed to post it publicly anyway. I just needed to follow the data in one specific situation. Rewriting all the cursor-using code would take months of full-time work: my boss would laugh in my face if I suggested it, which I won't.

Comment: That's no justification to use cursors. They aren't needed for what you describe in the first place. As for the 15 years, you have to fix the bugs at *some* point. Otherwise the debt becomes so huge that you can't fix it. Cursors were abandoned for a reason - they are slow, they cause blocking and use excessive locks. They are the slowest way you can process data. They are also a great way to waste CPU cores by forcing sequential exeuction

Comment: As for batch updating multiple rows, a set operation is a *lot* faster because the server doesn't have to keep lock for long. You can store changed data in a temporary table and just perform a single UPDATE with the target table

Comment: The one case where you lose, and just have to wait unitl you find a better company, is the case where an application started small and performed data manipulation on the client. As it grew, it was easier to keep doing so instead of replacing it with SQL. At some point, it's just impossible to untangle the code, even if SQL is 100 and 1000 times faster.

Comment: And then comes that time where the cursors and client data processing can't handle the new contract no matter what, resulting in cancellations and penalties. Not all companies survive this

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I did ask how to use cursors in one particular aspect. i did not ask whether to use cursors. I see plenty of people discussing how to use them, and I must conclude that yours is a minority, extremist view, and pay no attention to it. You seem to ignore my statements that in this application cursors are NOT causing blocking, are not  causing slowdowns, and are not a bug. We are not getting "cancellations and penalties" nor client complaints, and we are handling large numbers of transactions perfectly well.

Comment: Then please google for "Disconnected Recordsets". As for minority and extremist - .NET never had support for cursors for a reason. Anyway, David Browne already answered

Answer (score 3):

```
select c.*
from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_cursors(s.session_id) c
```

David